# Conexion a base de datos MySql atraves de android studio

Tags: mysql, android-studio, conexión

Estoy recién iniciando en esto de móviles y tenia una gran cuestión en particular,¿como puedo conectarme a una base de datos en android studio?,cuando intento hacerlo me sale el siguiente error: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.

a continuación dejo el codigo que estoy usando, aqui es donde tengo la conexion, es una clase de java llamada DatabaseHelper

```
package com.befj.session2;


import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DatabaseHelper{

   public boolean Conectarmysql(){
       boolean estadodeconexion = false;
       Connection conexionmysql = null;

       String user = "root";
       String password = "12345";
       String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/nombredelabd";
       String Driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";

       try {
           Class.forName(Driver).newInstance();
           conexionmysql = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, user, password);
           if (!conexionmysql.isClosed()) {
               estadodeconexion = true;
               System.out.println("Conexion exitosa");
           }
           }catch(Exception ex) {
           System.out.println("Conexion no exitosa" + ex);
       }
       finally {
           try {
               conexionmysql.close();
           }
           catch (SQLException e){
               e.printStackTrace();
               System.out.println("Conexion no exitosa" + e);
           }
       }
       return estadodeconexion;

   }

}
```

aqui dejo la clase del MainActivity que es el que contiene una parte visual del activity y que es el que se corre por defecto

```
package com.befj.session2;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseHelper databse = new DatabaseHelper();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        databse.Conectarmysql();

    }

}
```

Gracias.